# Django restauth new field creation in registration

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am using Django rest auth library for registration and login, now I want to introduce a new field in the registration form, I have managed to do it by adding the field in rest auth library directly, it is the best way or any other way to do it like overriding. so without override let say for an example: if i am doing the changes in the rest auth library so if any update on rest auth library will create any impact on changes which i have done.

Comment: to make this clear. You changed this file `django.contrib.auth.models` to get another field for the User model?

Comment: no i have added the field in rest_auth library inside site-packages

Comment: it is being a third party library [link](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) you can refer more information

Comment: ok I wrote you some code how I did it I hope that helps. If you want to use this library good luck with it I never used it.